# difference between class<type> vs class in template member function

Tags: c++, templates

When should I use `class<type>` vs `class` and what's the difference? eg.

```
template<typename T>
class cls
{
    ...
    cls & operator= (cls const & c)
    ...
};
```

vs.

```
template<typename T>
class cls
{
    ...
    cls<T> & operator= (cls<T> const & c)
    ...
};
```